# Moving site; new SSL

Tags: ssl

I have a site on AWS with an SSL. The site is an ec2 instance and runs WordPress.

I wanted to move the site out of Wordpress, so I have a different ec2 instance with the new site.

The domain will remain the same and I want to minimize downtime during the switchover. Can I get a new SSL for the new site before the domain DNS points there? I know the connection won't show it's secure until the SSL it matches the domain.

Is there another way to handle the migration?

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible. How you do it depends on the SSL provider you're using.

Comment: This isn't really on-topic on StackOverflow (our scope is writing code -- questions more focused on system administration are a better fit for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)) -- but you can request a certificate with a SubjectAltName to get a single cert that's valid for two different domain names. Though if the domain isn't changing, why do you need a new cert/key pair at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain isn't changing then as far as SSL is concerned neither is your site. You just need to properly configure the new site to use the same SSL certificate. To minimize downtime move the AWS Elastic IP to the new ec2 instance during migration. If done correctly you'll have no downtime at all.

Comment: so I can simple move the AWS Elastic IP to the new instance? Nothing needs to change on the SSL?

Comment: Correct, just make sure the new server provides the same SSL certificate.